# php session_start() is working in WP enging but not worked in live site

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a site which has wp engine for work. I have added php session_start() in wp engine and its worked fine. But my live not working with php session_start();. Live site created session but after redirecting its session has been blank, may session has destroyed. But same functionality using in live and staging site, then why not working session in live site? I have many answer in this forum and I am also implement this code, but not working. How can I solve this issue?

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your live site too in WP Engine which unfortunately **not supports PHP sessions** due to their specific cache setup. You can read more here - https://wpengine.com/support/cookies-and-php-sessions/. WP Engine cache might be disabled in your staging environment and that's why PHP sessions working.

**Solution:** You need to switch to PHP cookies (or) disable WP Engine cache.

Comment: Would you please let me know that, from where I will disable the Wp Engine cache?

Comment: I am facing the same kind of issue with the WpEngine sessions.

Comment: Things are changed now in WP Engine. Try https://wpengine.com/support/wp-engines-object-caching/ or contact their support.